# Нужны ли указанные запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые?

> Он родился в Москве(,) 12 мая 1966
> года(,) в семье музыкантов.

Всегда считала, что здесь они не нужны. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятые не нужны, потому что это три разные члена предложения, отвечающие на разные вопросы, т.е. нет однородных членов и нет уточняющих членов

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Если Вас устроил ответ, можете принять его, кликнув на ярлык